# How to add points(overlays) over a route in map in android

Tags: android, maps, draw, routes, overlays

I need to draw route on google maps in my android map and display few places and start and end point over the route as pins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this : http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/mapOverlayDemo.html